# What would be the simplest way to send a live video stream from a PC to a native iOS or Android app, with very low latency

Tags: android, ios, streaming, webrtc, nvenc

I am trying to send a live video feed from a PC to a native Android or iOS app. The connection will be over wifi. The App in return will send back it's SLAM AR tracking to the PC. The PC will update it's camera position and send new video. Essentially it's rendering AR for a tablet on a PC over wifi.

The PC client is running Unreal with Pixel Streaming over WebRTC. This already works great in the browser. But the tablet has to be running ARKit or ARCore at all times, which does not work in a browser. Embedding a browser in the ARKit or ARCore app does not work because the in-app browsers don't fully support WebRTC.

So it would have to be a native video player that supports WebRTC. And a way to send the WebRTC stream from Unreal to the native app.

So what is a good way to send a h264 WebRTC stream from a PC?
And how would I go about building a video player in iOS or Android that can receive a WebRTC stream?